# Julia Distributed - why the variable is not defined on worker after evaluating the expression?

Tags: julia

```
function pass_object(src::Int, target::Vector{Int8}, name::Symbol; from_mod=Main, to_mod=Main)
    r = RemoteChannel(src)
    @sync @spawnat(src, put!(r, getfield(from_mod, name)))
    @sync for to in target
        @spawnat(to, Core.eval(to_mod, Expr(:(=), name, fetch(r))))
    end
end

variable1 = some_data
@sync pass_object(1, pid, :variable1)
result = @spawnat pid Core.eval(Main, :(new_variable=variable1))
```

Julia 1.5.3

I tried multiple ways how to pass object to another worker and then use the assigned variable, but the result is always that it is not defined. There are no errors before I try to access its attribute, e.g. remotecall_fetch(println, pid, new_variable.label)

Any ideas why this does not work? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ParallelDataTransfer` for that. For an example.

```
using ParallelDataTransfer, Distributed
addprocs(1)
@everywhere using ParallelDataTransfer, Distributed

variable1 = [1,2,3]
@passobj 1 2 variable1
```

Now some console tests:

```
julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 sum(variable1))
6

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 variable1[1]=1000)
1000

julia> sum(variable1)
6

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 sum(variable1))
1005
```

Comment: Thanks, ParallelDataTransfer works like a charm. I still have some problems, but now I know that they are related to other parts of my code.